# Input validation message toggle for blur and focusIn

Tags: antd

I want to trigger the validation only for input "blur" instead of typing on it. So I have used the method `validateTrigger:'onBlur'` and its worked fine for me as expected. After user focus/click again the input, the validation message should disappear, any solution?

```
<FormItem>
{getFieldDecorator('email', {
    rules: [
        {
          type: 'email', message: 'Valid E-mail required!',
        },
        { required: true, message: 'E-mail required!', whitespace:true }
    ],
    validateTrigger:'onBlur'
})(
    <Input
        placeholder="Email"
    />
)}
```

Answer (score 3):

This can be done by using [ant design validateStatus](https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-validate-static) parameter. You can dynamically change the statuses from given sets, i.e, 'success', 'warning', 'error', 'validating'.

> validateStatus: validate status of form components which could be 'success', 'warning', 'error', 'validating'.

You need to functions, one `onBlur` and other `onFocus`. `FormItem` can be written as:

```
        <FormItem
          validateStatus={this.state.showError && userNameError ? "error" : ""}
          help={
            this.state.showError && userNameError
              ? "Valid E-mail required!"
              : ""
          }
        >
          {getFieldDecorator("userName", {
            validateTrigger: "onBlur",
            rules: [
              { type: "email", message: "Valid E-mail required!" },
              { required: true, message: "Please input your username!" }
            ]
          })(
            <Input
              placeholder="Email"
              onBlur={this.handleBlur}
              onFocus={this.handleFocus}
            />
          )}
        </FormItem>
```

And the two methods can be written as:

```
  handleBlur = e => {
    this.setState({ showError: true });
  };

  handleFocus = e => {
    this.setState({ showError: false });
  };
```

Working demo is on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/o5n0p7l7mq).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have accomplished it by using method 'validateTrigger' and 'setFields'.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with Ant Design (v5) that they validate on input change. This causes bad UX when the user starts typing something and immediately sees that the input is invalid (e.g. email is not valid). Better is to use "onBlur" first and after that "onChange" trigger. Check this [issue](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12542) in Ant Design and this suggested [solution](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/12542#issuecomment-1500674291). I found that Formik behaves like that out of the box.